# Mostrar un id (clave primaria) en dos tablas relacionadas PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, registro

tengo un problema en donde no sé si me puedan ayudar.
Tengo una base de datos con dos tablas llamadas **Cliente** y **Empleado** donde cada uno tienen los siguientes atributos:

**Cliente**

Id_cliente(pk),
Nombre,
Edad

**Empleado**

Municipio,
Estado,
Correo,
id_cliente(fk)

Lo que quiero realizar es que por medio de un formulario registre todos los atributos mencionados a **excepción** de la llave primaria que se generará automáticamente en la base de datos a la hora de registrar los datos, para que después por medio de un código PHP inserte los registros en la base de datos en sus respectivas tablas.

El problema es que a la hora de registrar los datos solo se guardan los datos de la tabla **Cliente** mientras que en la tabla **Empleado** no se guarda ningún registro y tampoco arrastra la llave primaria generada en ese momento.

A continuación anexo mi código PHP donde según inserto los registros.

```
<?php

require_once("conexion.php");

$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO
 Cliente(
  Nombre, 
  Edad
 ) VALUES (
 '".$_POST["Nombre"]."',
 ".$_POST["Edad"]."
 )");
 
$id_cliente = mysql_insert_id(); //Recuperando el ultimo id generado

$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO Empleado(
Municipio,
Estado,
Correo,
id_cliente
) VALUES (
'".$_POST["Municipio"]."',
'".$_POST["Estado"]."',
'".$_POST["Correo"]."',
'$id_cliente'
)");

?>
```

Como había comentado, solo aparecen los registros de la tabla **Cliente** en la base de datos pero no de la otra. Espero y me ayuden a solucionar el problema de arrastrar la llave primaria a la otra tabla junto con sus atributos.

Gracias.

Comment: Agrega estas tres líneas al inicio de tu script y dinos qué errores ves en pantalla: `ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_insert_id()

Comment: Eso es lo que apareció en pantalla

Comment: Tienes que agregarle la `i`, o sea: `$id_cliente=mysqli_insert_id();`  o bien usar el estilo orientado a objetos para dar uniformidad a tu código: `$id_cliente=$mysqli->insert_id;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La función que estás usando para recuperar el último ID corresponde a la vieja API de mysqli (esas funciones se escribían todas sin la `i` al final).

```
$id_cliente = mysql_insert_id(); //Recuperando el ultimo id generado
```

Puedes corregir tu código así:

```
$id_cliente = mysqli_insert_id(); //Recuperando el ultimo id generado
```

O bien usar el estilo orientado a objetos, para dar coherencia a tu código:

```
$id_cliente=$mysqli->insert_id;
```

#### Nota sobre la seguridad

Tus instrucciones SQL son altamente vulnerables a ataques de *Inyección SQL*. Deberías implementar consultas preparadas para prevenir ese grave agujero de seguridad.

Comment: Le agradezco mucho su ayuda, me funciono. Tendré en cuenta las consultas preparadas para una mejor seguridad. Gracias